# Messagebox dialog for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, popup, messagebox

I have tried to use console.writeline, opendialog, messagebox for my web application on visual studio 2005, but all of them seems to have a missing reference. May I know what is to be used in VS 2005 for popup message boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `Response.Write();` to output your result on web-page

Answer (score 4):

Console is for console applications; MessageBox is for windows forms. There is no built-in message box for web forms, other than the JavaScript `alert` method:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('this is a message');">Alert me</a>
```

Comment: it still says The name 'alert' does not exist in the current context. im testing it on an example like 


connection.Open();
    alert("connection opened");

Comment: You cant use alert in your asp.net code you need to use it in javascript. All you can deliver to your client is a prerendered htmlpage you can't invoke clientstuff dynamically while the page is compiling. The closest thing is doing everything with ajaxcalls and invoke javascript alerts when you recieve the response.

Comment: See also this blog post, http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/12/01/asp-net-alerts-how-to-display-message-boxes-from-server-side-code.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net uses two separate worlds that alternate in having control:

1) the **server**, where you use database connections to retrieve data and prepare html for sending to the browser. Only when the server is finished, a response is sent back to the browser

2) the **browser**, which renders the html to show a page to the user. On some action of the user (usually), a new request is sent to the server for another round.

So you can't mix user-interaction with server-side code, the way you can with a winform application.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine opening a web site and a message in a console to be written to you. It's not good, right? That's why you can use Response.WriteLine() in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to write out to the built-in trace thing, especially if you're in the data layer opening DB connections.  E.g. Debug.Write or Trace.Write, then, while debugging, look in the Output window in VS and select Show output from: Debug.  You can also see the messages in http://server/yourapp/trace.axd.

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(v=VS.85).aspx